# Can the center of a circle be considered a pole with a polar line?

Tags: geometry, circles

> Can the center of a circle be considered a pole with a polar line?

I read few web pages. Some of them said that a pole can be any point in the plane of circle, while some say it cannot be the center of the circle.

Please clarify for me.

Comment: In projective geometry it is convenient to extend the plane with a 'line at infinity'. In your case, the inverse of the center with respect to the circle is the closest point of the polar of the center of the circle to the center of the circle. Therefore, the line at infinity is the polar line of the center. You can not add the line at infinity, and not have a polar for the center, or add the line at infinity and allow the center to be a pole.

Comment: Sorry but i did'nt get it can you please explain in more simple language.

Comment: Given a point,$A$ you can construct its polar with respect to a circle with center $O$, by constructing the inverse $A'$ of the point with respect to the circle. Then drawing the perpendicular line at $A'$ to the line $OA$ gives you the polar. Well, if $A$ is $O$, then its inverse is infinitely far. That inverse point is supposed to be the closest point to $O$ of the polar. Therefore all the points of the polar should be infinitely far away. So, you can extend the plane with a line of infinitely far points, and now the origin also has a polar line.

Comment: As per the definition of polar that i know it is the locus of point of intersection of tangents drawn at the points of intersection of circle and secant lines drawn from the pole. So according to it there is no problem in considering centre of the circle as pole

Comment: Well, when the pole is at the center, the secant lines are diameters. So, the tangents turn out to be parallel.

Comment: Thanks i got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the plane your circle lives in. In a standard Euclidean plane, the center has no polar line. In the projective plane, the polar of the center is the line at infinity.

You can observe that as a point approaches the center, it's polar moves increasingly further away from the circle. In projective geometry the limit of this process had its own well-defined representation.

Comment: I am in 12th std. So what shuld i conclude finally?